# Expected value of the minimum of 3 cards

Tags: probability, card-games

Is this question it is shown that the probability of a minimum is:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-random-variables-distributed

$1-[1-F_X(x)]^n$

I have a problem where I'm asked to find the minimum (m) of 3 cards drawn from a pack of 52 (no jokers) where jack=11, queen=12 and king=13.

So I'm trying to apply the above logic.

$P(m \leq k) = [1-[1-\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{j}{13}]^3$

However the solution  given states that:

$P(m\geq k)=(1-P(X_1\leq k-1))^3=(1- \frac{k-1}{13})^3$

I'm firstly confused by why they calculate $P(m \geq k)$ tather than $P(m \leq k)$?
Is the solution in the book correct and if so where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What should $\sum_{j=1}^k\frac j{13}$ mean?

Comment: I am trying to solve the problem using the methodology in the used in the link but it seems to be giving different answer given in the book. Looking at the first equation above to calculate the probability that the minimum is less than k you must calculate the probability that each of the cards is more than k which obviously is [1-F(k)]^n then subtract this from 1 to get 1-[1-F(k)]^n which is the probability that m is less than or equal to k. So the summation above is meant to be the discrete cdf. However this does not seem to give the same answer as the book.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the probability to draw a card with cost $k$ or higher is
$$
P_1(m\ge k)=1-\frac{k-1}{13},\;k=1\dots13,
$$
and the probability to draw such a card three times (provided we draw with replacement) is just the cube of the probability:
$$
P_3(m\ge k)=\left(1-\frac{k-1}{13}\right)^3,
$$
so that the book gives the correct value.

Correspondingly
$$
P_3(m<k)=1-P_3(m\ge k)=\left[1-\left(1-\frac{k-1}{13}\right)^3\right].
$$

Comment: I can follow the logic in the book, I just can't reconcile it with the approach used in the link, they should give the same answer?  One part of the books solution that I'm not clear on is that they are calculating the probability that m (the minimum) is more than k?) Surely it would make more sense to calculate the probability that m is less than k? Which would be 1- the above?

Comment: This solution is correct only if the draw is made with replacement.

Comment: The draw is made with replacement.

Comment: @nicola You are correct. I have added the mention of this into the answer.

Comment: @Bazman You are correct. The probability that $m$ is less than $k$ is 1- the above. The question is what is of interest: "less than" or "less than or equal to". By continuous random variable it makes no difference but in discrete case it does.